# Relacionamento N-N com campos adicionais (problemas para persistir os dados)

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, java-ee, jpa

Tenho um relacionamento N-N que funciona da seguinte forma:

**Destination.java (N)-(N) CustomerService.java**

Dentro desse relacionamento existe uma entidade que guarda os Id's dos relacionamentos, que possui alguns valores a mais. O nome de tal é **ServiceItem.java**

Abaixo as entity's:

**Destination.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="destination")
public class Destination implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_destination")
    private Long idDestination;

    @Column(name="tenant_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Long tenantId;

    @Column(name="appear_website")
    private Boolean dtAppearWebsite;

    @Lob
    @Column(name="description")
    @NotEmpty(message="O campo \"Descrição do Destino\" não pode estar em branco.")
    private String dtDescription;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="destination")
    private Set<ServiceItem> serviceItem;

    //Mais campos adicionais e Getters and Setters

    public Destination() {
    }
}
```

**CustomerService.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_service")
public class CustomerService implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_customer_service")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "tenant_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long tenantId;

    @Column(name = "date_service")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date;

    @Column(name = "average_budget")
    private BigDecimal averageBudget;

    @Column(name = "service_situation")
    private boolean situation;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "customerService")
    private List<ServiceItem> serviceItem;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_history")
    private History history;

    @Column(name = "service_observatons")
    private String serviceObservations;

    public CustomerService() {

    }

    //Mais campos adicionais e Getters and Setters

}
```

**ServiceItem.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "service_item")
@IdClass(ServiceItemId.class)
public class ServiceItem {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="destination_id")
    private Destination destination;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="customerService_id")
    private CustomerService customerService;

    @Column(name="tenant_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Long tenantId;   

    @Column(name="value_negotiated")
    private double valueNegotiated;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="sale_type")
    private SaleType saleType;

    @Column(name="departure_date")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date departureDate;

    @Column(name="arrival_date")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date arrivalDate;

    @Column(name="requested_destination")
    private Boolean requestedDestination;

    @Column(name="negociation_observations")
    private String negociationObservations;

    public ServiceItem() {

    }

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

Para gerar os id's existe a classe **ServiceItemId.java**

```java
public class ServiceItemId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long destination;
    private Long customerService;

    public Long getCustomerService() {
        return customerService;
    }
    public void setCustomerService(Long customerService) {
        this.customerService = customerService;
    }
    public Long getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }
    public void setDestination(Long destination) {
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (int) (destination + customerService);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof ServiceItemId){
            ServiceItemId serviceItemId = (ServiceItemId) obj;
            return serviceItemId.destination == destination && serviceItemId.customerService == customerService;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

Bem, a questão é quando eu vou persistir os dados...

```
Dez 17, 2014 4:52:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/viatge] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20131113-a7346c6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'customerService_id' cannot be null
Error Code: 1048
Call: INSERT INTO service_item (arrival_date, departure_date, negociation_observations, requested_destination, sale_type, value_negotiated, customerService_id, destination_id, tenant_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [2016-08-01, 2015-10-01, teste, true, SUBMITTED_BUDGET, 3658.98, null, 1, 2]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(br.com.joocebox.model.ServiceItem@6e92b1b1)] with root cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'customerService_id' cannot be null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1041)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4187)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4119)
```

Eu até entendo que esteja faltando informar o id **customerService_id** na entidade de ServiceItem.java, mas esse id vai ser gerado automaticamente, pois é incorreto eu informar o id na mão.

Como poderia proceder em tal caso?

### EDIÇÃO

Vamos lá!

Minha entity **CustomerService** (que se refere ao um atendimento) possui muitos destinos (nesse caso **Destination**), tal como muitos destinos podem pertencer a muitos CustomerService.java (atendimento).

Note que não existe um relacionamento **@ManyToMany** diretamente entre as entidades, mas existe uma classe chamada ServiceItem que faz a união entre as duas entidades.

Quando vou persistir um ServiceItem, meu id referente a Destination é carregado, (pois já existe), já o CustomerService ainda não foi persistido, logo ele não vai ter um ID o que é o causador do problema.

Comment: Porque é incorreto informar o ID "na mão" ? De onde foi tirada essa informação ?
Você pode muito bem utilizar um método com @PrePersist e atribuir um UUID à sua chave por exemplo. É oque eu costumo utilizar, ainda mais em sistemas distribuídos, é a solução mais rápida que eu vejo para evitar gargalo com geração de id sequencial em ambiente concorrente.

Não sei se entendi bem seu requerimento (especifique melhor caso minha resposta esteja vaga). Do ponto de vista de negócio, é necessário ter uma chave primária composta ?porque não apenas utiliza utilizar um campo específico para o ID ?

Comment: Bem, @JosuéEduardo, no meu entendimento não seria uma "boa pratica" informar os id's, mas parece que estou enganado. Bem Estou realizando o mapeamento entre as entidade de forma Muitos-para-Muitos com campos adicionais. A forma da qual foi feita foi a mesma encontrado neste link: http://uaihebert.com/jpa-mini-livro-primeiros-passos-e-conceitos-detalhados/22/. Bem é que estou acostumado a cada nova "inserção" em banco não informar o id, logo não sei como sanar o erro descrito na pergunta, pois minha ideia era que customerService_id fosse gerado automaticamente. Grato pelo esclarecimento

Comment: So mais um detalhe: infelizmente o ServiceItemId.hashCode() foi implementado incorretamente, 1+2=3 e 2+1=3, aconselho a dar uma olhada aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034328/hashcode-for-objects-with-only-integers... 

Referente a dúvida em questão: você têm certeza de que as duas entidades que compõe a chave primária não são nulas ? se tiver mais algum detalhe sobre o estado do Destination e CustomerService acho que iria nos ajudar um pouco melhor. Oque me parece é que ServiceItem não foi instanciada.

Comment: Não vou ser longo pois estou de um celular. Mas vou ser direto. 1- Quando 1 vi N-N no título, imaginei a associação MUITOS para MUITOS (fui procurar a anotação @ManyToMany e não encontrei); 2- Estou achando esse modo de mapeamento muito confuso, se você tem chaves compostas, porquê não usa  o Embeddable ?; 3- Evite ao máximo usar o PrePersist, se um id é necessário ser gerado, deixe isso explicito na camada de negócio do seu software; 4- como citado anteriormente, implemente corretamente o hashCode.

Comment: Obrigado pela observação da má implementação do hashCode(), irei corrigir. Então, elas não são nulas. O problema ocorre com o id da CustomerService, pois ainda não foi persistida em banco, logo ocorre o problema de integridade. O serviceItem não consegue realizar o insert justamente pelo motivo que falta o id de CustomerService. A questão é se existe como realizar a geração de tal id automaticamente. ou eu devo gravar primeiro um CustomerService para assim depois gravar um ServiceItem?

Comment: @wryel, tal exemplo foi pego em livros e em sites, pois estou usando a abordagem N-N com campos adicionais (http://uaihebert.com/jpa-mini-livro-primeiros-passos-e-conceitos-detalhados/22/). Até agora só conheço essa abordagem.

Comment: Então faz assim por favor, edita sua pergunta e ali no final  coloque o cenário que você está tentando realizar, ex: 1 pessoa tem N Filhos, 1 Filho tem N carrinhos. Deixa mais claro pra gente que estamos tentando ajudar. (Aproveitando, o problema dessa anotacao IdClass é que ela casa mais com sistemas legados, do que sistemas novos, na qual Embeddable faz bem mais sentido [de fato você faz uma classe que assume a identidade de uma entidade])

Comment: @wryel, fiz a edição mitigando bem a situação, assim como alterei a pergunta (espero que esteja legal).

Comment: @JosuéEduardo, estava lendo sobre a implementação de um UUID para id (realizando um @PrePersist) e achei que resolverá perfeitamente meu problema. Para ser sincero não conhecia essa forma de geração de id's. Você poderia me ilustrar um exemplo e comentar (se não for muito trabalhoso) quais as vantagens e desvantagens de tal abordagem? Grato!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondendo à discussão nos comentários:
Tanto a utilização de UUID(GUID) quanto de ID têm seus prós e contras.

Os detalhes mais técnicos deixo para o post original, qual essa resposta se baseia:

[SOen - advantages-and-disadvantages-of-guid-uuid-database-keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45399/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-guid-uuid-database-keys)

[SOen - how-do-you-like-your-primary-keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404040/how-do-you-like-your-primary-keys)

[SOen - generate-uuid-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325443/generate-uuid-in-java)

Segue um simples exemplo, note que [@PrePersist](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PrePersist.html) será executado pelo seu framework ORM. Mais detalhes sobre listener de entidades [AQUI](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/listeners.html).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "service_item")
public class ServiceItem {

    @Id
    //Long ? Integer ?
    private String uuid;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="destination_id")
    private Destination destination;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="customerService_id")
    private CustomerService customerService;


    @PrePersist
    public void init() {
        //Aqui voce gera seu GUID
        //Note que existem varios outros meios
        //Estou utilizando esse pois é nativo e pratico
        this.uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: infelizmente acabou não funcionando. fiz a implementação na minha entity CustomerService.java seguindo esse tutorial http://www.thebinaryidiot.com/archives/2011/06/25/jpa-and-uuid-primary-keys/, mas o erro ainda persiste. Bem confesso que não sei mais para onde correr. Creio que agora a maneira que mais se adequaria ao meu problema seria eu persistir meu objeto CustomerService perimeiro, para que em sequencia (já com o id do CustomerService), eu possa gravar o serviceItem.

Comment: @JoãoManolo, se uma entidade C possui referencia para outras duas entidades A e B, no momento de persistir C, A e B devem estar no contexto de persistência (já persistidas). Isso é uma regra fundamental de DB. Quanto ao exemplo que te passei, note que não existe mágica, voce pode ao invés de usar o método anotado com @PrePersist, atribuir diretamente um uuid: `serviceItem.setUuid("uuid-123")` para depois inserir na base, sem problemas. Quanto ao seu problema você deverá inserir tanto `Destination`, quanto `CustomerService` antes de persistir `ServiceItem`